# Undefined variable no Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tendo a seguinte mensagem de erro no meu projeto:

> Undefined variable: banner (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\painelEda\resources\views\alterar-banner.blade.php)

Enquanto na minha view `banner.blade.php` está deste modo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('banner.update', $banner->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ method_field('PUT') }
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-9">
                                <label for="simpleinput">Título</label>
                                <input type="text" value="{{ $banner->titulo or old('titulo') }}" id="simpleinput" class="form-control" name="titulo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                                <label for="example-date">Texto</label>
                                <input class="form-control" value="{{ $banner->imagem or old('imagem') }}" id="example-date" type="date" name="imagem">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                <input class="form-control" value="{{ $banner->descricao or old('descricao') }}" name="descricao"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

O controller está assim:

```
public function index(){
    $banners = Banner::all();
    $total = Banner::all()->count();
    return view('banner', compact('banners', 'total'));
}

public function create(){
    return view('adicionar-banner');
}

public function store(Request $request){
    $banners = new Banner;
    $banners->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $banners->descricao = $request->descricao;
    $banners->imagem = $request->imagem;
    $banners->save();
    return redirect()->route('banner.index')->with('message', 'Banner publicado com sucesso!');
}

public function show($id) {

}

public function edit($id) {
    $banners = Banner::findOrFail($id);
    return view('alterar-banner', compact('banner'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $$banners = Banner::findOrFail($id);
    $banners->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $banners->descricao = $request->descricao;
    $banners->save();
    return redirect()->route('banner.index')->with('message', 'Banner alterado com sucesso!');
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Você provavelmente não está passando a variavel `banner` do controller pra sua view. Ou o nome da variavel está incorreta. Edite a pergunta e insira o conteudo do seu controller

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei o controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o controller fica mais fácil de exemplificar... Veja se do jeito abaixo resolve o seu problema...

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    **$banner** = Banner::findOrFail($id);
    $banner->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $banner->descricao = $request->descricao;
    $banner->save();
    return redirect()->route('banner.index', ['banner' => $banner, 'message' => 'Banner alterado com sucesso!']);
}
```

Comment: Adicionei o meu controller pra que possa entender

Answer (score 1):

Na função edit do seu controller, troque o nome da variável **banners**:

```
 $banners = Banner::findOrFail($id);
```

Para **banner**:

```
 $banner = Banner::findOrFail($id);
```

Já que a função `compact` utilizada no seu retorno espera uma variável local com o nome `banner` e ela não está sendo definida passará a `view` como uma variável indefinida

Comment: Show! Funcionou. Muito obrigado!